# Jquery validate custom css checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Is there a way to validate the following checkbox ?

```html
<form name="rmn-form" id="rmn-form" action="send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="rmn-input-field">
        <label for="gdpr" class="checkbox-container"> Accept terms and conditions
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="gdpr" name="gdpr">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-all" class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-button pink mt-30">Send</button>
</form>
```

The checkbox is generated by https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

I have the following JSFiddle with my code with the bootstrap library and jquery.validate.min.js:
http://jsfiddle.net/2837qdeu/

Comment: it is working in your fiddle, what is the issue?

Comment: The validation is not working in the fiddle.

Comment: Hey Stefan - Ce mai faci? Just following up. Was your question answered? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to ask for more help. ***Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (click the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question - doing so costs you nothing but helps the other guy.*** If no answer was helpful, please post your own and select it with the checkmark to close out the question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your input tag to the code below

```
<input type="checkbox" required="required" id="gdpr" name="gdpr">
```

It will check before submit that this checkbox must be checked.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uw5tsoa/)

Answer (score 0):

You also can take control of this yourself, as below:

```
 $("[name=submit]").click(function(){
    if ( $('#gdpr').is(':checked') ){
        alert('submit will proceed - checkbox is checked') //This alert not required, only added for demo
    }else{
        alert('Error - submit will not proceed');
        return false; //<== Here is the magic, along with checking that the box is checked
    }
 });
```

[Revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmpLsghv/)

---

`return false` will stop the submit procedure, allowing you to display a message, or do some js wizardry, before returning control to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line in the js file and it worked just fine:

```
$("#rmn-form").validate({
    ignore: ':hidden:not(:checkbox)',
    ....
});
```